# jMeter CSV Data Set Config - running multiple users simultaniously fails

Tags: csv, jmeter

I've managed to get everything up and running to a certain point, but now I'm stuck. I hope you can help.

I've used those instructions from Blazemeter regarding the CSV config. https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config

I have one Thread Group, where I

- retrieve the Bearer Token and store it as a property variable
- I login with a username & password (the information is stored in the CSV file and this works well)
- I then add an item to a shopping basket (where a User ID is required, this information is also stored in the CSV file).

When I set the Thread Group settings to

- Number of Threads: 1
- Loop count: 6
  everything works as it should. On every iteration, a new line from the CSV file is used and it runs from User01 to User06. The CSV Data config is set to "All Threads" at this point. I added the JSR223 Assertion to see which User from the CSV file is picked to analyse the issue. I will remove it later. The below image shows all 6 iterations ran successfully.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VilDL.png)

Now my problem:
when I try and run 2 users simultaneously, the test cases started to fail. I tried different settings in CSV, like "Current Thread Group" and "all Threads".

At first, 2 AuthCode-4 run (this is the part where we retrieve the Bearer Token), where the first one shows "User01" and the second "User02". That means it works as it should so far. Later in the script, I get auth errors. I also have figured out why. When User02 runs, the Bearer Token variable overwrites the Bearer Token from User01. That means the authentication fails for User01 for further requests.

The solution would be to store the Bearer Token, after it ran for each user, in the CSV file and call it later from there. But how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

> retrieve the Bearer Token and store it as a property variable

If you want each user to have its own token please don't store it as a property, leave it to be a variable.

As per [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; **properties are common to all threads**

If you really need to have it a a property use [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) as the property name prefix or postfix so each virtual user would have its own property with the token.

If you still want to write the token into the CSV file take a look at [Flexbile File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#writer)

Comment: Thanks again Dimitri. This worked. The Bearer token was one of the very first things I did when I started with jMeter. The online example I found turned them into property variables and I think I never questioned it since. This helped me a lot.